# How to add/remove class on one element when hovering over a separate element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I have a speech bubble (image in the centre) with an accompanying piece of text. Below this is four buttons.  The idea is that when a user hovers over a button the speech bubble and accompanying and text will change.

I have got that part working by using siblings, however I want the first speech bubble to be active when the page initially loads and when a user hovers over a button the active class will be removed from this and applied to the new speech bubble.

How can I achieve that?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.spanWrappers').hover(function() {
    $(".show-span").addClass("active");
  }, function() {
    $(".show-span").removeClass("active");
  });

});
```

```css
.bubble {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  width: 335px;
  float: left;
  left: 8px;
  top: 28px;
}

span.one:hover+.show-span {
  display: block;
}

span.two:hover+.show-span {
  display: block;
}

span.three:hover+.show-span {
  display: block;
}

span.four:hover+.show-span {
  display: block;
}

.show-span {
  display: none;
}

.show-span:active {
  display: block;
}

.top {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 460px;
  /*       height: 500px;*/
  /*        height: 55vh;*/
  background: url(img/banner-1.svg), #2e4355;
  background-size: 110%, cover;
  background-position: center bottom, center;
  background-position-y: 100.5%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.roll-icon-1,
.roll-icon-2,
.roll-icon-3,
.roll-icon-4 {
  z-index: 2;
  width: 45px;
}

.roll-icon-1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 26px;
  top: 395px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.roll-icon-2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 97px;
  top: 422px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.roll-icon-3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 175px;
  top: 424px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.roll-icon-4 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 255px;
  top: 393px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.swap img:last-child {
  display: none
}

.swap:hover img:first-child {
  display: none
}

.swap:hover img:last-child {
  display: inline-block
}

.bubble-widget {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display: block;
  /*background-color: pink;*/
  max-width: 800px;
  height: 520px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  align-content: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 111px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bubble-widget">
  <div class="spanWrappers">
    <span class="one">
      <img class="roll-icon-1" src="https://placeimg.com/85/83/buildings">
      </span>
    <span class="show-span:active">
         <img class="bubble" src="https://i.imgur.com/PQpLHWD.png"/>
         <p>text-title-1</p>
      </span>
  </div>
  <!--spanWrappers-->
  <div class="spanWrappers">
    <span class="two">
      <img class="roll-icon-2" src="https://placeimg.com/85/83/animals">
      </span>
    <span class="show-span">
         <img class="bubble" src="https://i.imgur.com/Y6S0iyq.png"/>
         <p>text-title-2</p>
      </span>
  </div>
  <!--spanWrappers-->
  <div class="spanWrappers">
    <span class="three">
      <img class="roll-icon-3" src="https://placeimg.com/85/83/people">
      </span>
    <span class="show-span">
         <img class="bubble" src="https://i.imgur.com/akhIh5Y.png"/>
         <p>text-title-3</p>
      </span>
  </div>
  <!--spanWrappers-->
  <div class="spanWrappers">
    <span class="four">
      <img class="roll-icon-4" src="https://placeimg.com/85/83/nature">
      </span>
    <span class="show-span">
         <img class="bubble" src="https://i.imgur.com/R9PF7kt.png"/>
         <p>text-title-4</p>
      </span>
  </div>
  <!--spanWrappers-->
</div>
```

here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joshtoan/ytbngh51/41/)  of what I have so far

Comment: `show-span:active` <-- why the `:` should be a space for a class. `.show-span.active { display: block;}`

Comment: @epascarello I changed it but it hasn't fixed my issue unfortunately, I get the same result either way

Comment: Did you change the `class="show-span:active"` to be `class="show-span active"`

Comment: It seems that you're handling the hovers with both CSS and jQuery. I.E. both `span.three:hover + .show-span` and `$(".show-span").addClass("active");`. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: @Jelly-Bandit You're getting there, better than the first iteration. Keep it up! :)

Comment: @Jelly-Bandit Did you get this working yet? If not I'll give it a try

Comment: @JoeKincognito not yet no, I will have another go at it tomorrow morning when im back at my computer

Comment: @showdev no reason besides me not really knowing what I am doing haha, I will remove the CSS and handle the hovers with jQuery only

Comment: @epascarello I did yes, but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As another users said in comments, you are triggering hover event both CSS and jQuery.

In this solution I used jQuery only to remove the first `active` you set in the page with a function that remove your `active` class at first `mouseover` on every `.show-span span:first-of-type` element, the rollover is delegate to CSS.

Your HTML is the same. I tried to clean your CSS only because there were rules 
repeated (I changed also `.show-span:active` with a more simple `.show-span .active`.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".spanWrappers span:first-of-type").one("mouseover", function(e){
    $(".show-span").removeClass("active")
  })
});
```

```css
.bubble {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  width: 335px;
  float: left;
  left: 8px;
  top: 28px;
}

.show-span {
  display: none;
}

.spanWrappers .show-span.active,
.spanWrappers span:first-of-type:hover + .show-span{
  display: block;
}


img[class^='roll']{
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 45px;
}


.roll-icon-1 {
  left: 26px;
  top: 395px;

}

.roll-icon-2 {
  left: 97px;
  top: 422px;
}

.roll-icon-3 {
  left: 175px;
  top: 424px;
}

.roll-icon-4 {
  left: 255px;
  top: 393px;
}


.bubble-widget {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display: block;
  /*background-color: pink;*/
  max-width: 800px;
  height: 520px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  align-content: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 111px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bubble-widget">
  <div class="spanWrappers">
    <span class="one">
      <img class="roll-icon-1" src="https://placeimg.com/85/83/buildings">
      </span>
    <span class="show-span active">
         <img class="bubble" src="https://i.imgur.com/PQpLHWD.png"/>
         <p>text-title-1</p>
      </span>
  </div>
  <!--spanWrappers-->
  <div class="spanWrappers">
    <span class="two">
      <img class="roll-icon-2" src="https://placeimg.com/85/83/animals">
      </span>
    <span class="show-span">
         <img class="bubble" src="https://i.imgur.com/Y6S0iyq.png"/>
         <p>text-title-2</p>
      </span>
  </div>
  <!--spanWrappers-->
  <div class="spanWrappers">
    <span class="three">
      <img class="roll-icon-3" src="https://placeimg.com/85/83/people">
      </span>
    <span class="show-span">
         <img class="bubble" src="https://i.imgur.com/akhIh5Y.png"/>
         <p>text-title-3</p>
      </span>
  </div>
  <!--spanWrappers-->
  <div class="spanWrappers">
    <span class="four">
      <img class="roll-icon-4" src="https://placeimg.com/85/83/nature">
      </span>
    <span class="show-span">
         <img class="bubble" src="https://i.imgur.com/R9PF7kt.png"/>
         <p>text-title-4</p>
      </span>
  </div>
  <!--spanWrappers-->
</div>
```

**EDIT 1**

For the question in your comment, I'd use only jQuery: working on `mouseover` function only (I changed also CSS, be careful).

```js
$(function() {
  $(".spanWrappers span:first-of-type").on("mouseover", function(e){
    $(".show-span").removeClass("active");
    $(this).next().addClass("active");
  })
});
```

```css
.bubble {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  width: 335px;
  float: left;
  left: 8px;
  top: 28px;
}

.show-span {
  display: none;
}

/*.spanWrappers .show-span.active,
.spanWrappers span:first-of-type:hover + .show-span{
  display: block;
}*/

.spanWrappers .show-span.active{
  display: block;
}


img[class^='roll']{
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 45px;
}


.roll-icon-1 {
  left: 26px;
  top: 395px;

}

.roll-icon-2 {
  left: 97px;
  top: 422px;
}

.roll-icon-3 {
  left: 175px;
  top: 424px;
}

.roll-icon-4 {
  left: 255px;
  top: 393px;
}


.bubble-widget {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display: block;
  /*background-color: pink;*/
  max-width: 800px;
  height: 520px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  align-content: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 111px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bubble-widget">
  <div class="spanWrappers">
    <span class="one">
      <img class="roll-icon-1" src="https://placeimg.com/85/83/buildings">
      </span>
    <span class="show-span active">
         <img class="bubble" src="https://i.imgur.com/PQpLHWD.png"/>
         <p>text-title-1</p>
      </span>
  </div>
  <!--spanWrappers-->
  <div class="spanWrappers">
    <span class="two">
      <img class="roll-icon-2" src="https://placeimg.com/85/83/animals">
      </span>
    <span class="show-span">
         <img class="bubble" src="https://i.imgur.com/Y6S0iyq.png"/>
         <p>text-title-2</p>
      </span>
  </div>
  <!--spanWrappers-->
  <div class="spanWrappers">
    <span class="three">
      <img class="roll-icon-3" src="https://placeimg.com/85/83/people">
      </span>
    <span class="show-span">
         <img class="bubble" src="https://i.imgur.com/akhIh5Y.png"/>
         <p>text-title-3</p>
      </span>
  </div>
  <!--spanWrappers-->
  <div class="spanWrappers">
    <span class="four">
      <img class="roll-icon-4" src="https://placeimg.com/85/83/nature">
      </span>
    <span class="show-span">
         <img class="bubble" src="https://i.imgur.com/R9PF7kt.png"/>
         <p>text-title-4</p>
      </span>
  </div>
  <!--spanWrappers-->
</div>
```

Comment: this is great thank you so much for your help, the first speech bubble is now active on page load. Follow up question however, do you know how i would make the last hovered remain active until the user hover over another button? Meaning that there is always a speech bubble on screen.

Comment: I edited my answer with my solution also for that. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Please use this code below, it will help you to sort your hovering issue

```
$('.spanWrappers').each(function() {
    $(this).find('img:first').on('mouseenter', function() {
        var activeSpan = $(this).parent().parent().find('span.show-span');
        activeSpan.addClass('show-span:active');
        activeSpan.removeClass('show-span');
        $(this).parent().parent().siblings().find('span').each(function() {
            var currentActive = $(this).attr('class');
            if(currentActive == 'show-span:active') {
                $(this).removeAttr('class').attr('class','show-span');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

But please note that, I will not recommend you to use CSS `pseudo classes` as it will become quite difficult for you to find an element with that class name which have pseudo class in it, so you should use active class instead to make element active.

Thanks

Comment: This looks like it might work but I don't have time to test it. Just one note: If you save a reference to $(this) on line 2 (var spanWrapper = $(this)) then you wouldn't have to do $(this).parent().parent()

Comment: I tested this suggestion and it does work. I added a variable to save a reference to the spanWrapper, as mentioned in my previous comment, on line 2 and used that in place of $(this).parent().parent(). Also, there are still a few issues with the code as mentioned in the answer above.